# removing subfolder out of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have successfully set up my .htaccess file to redirect website to subfolder using

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.org$ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.org$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L]
```

so when i go to my domain it will not show /subfolder/index.php

but when i visit a page on my website it will be www.domain.org/subfolder/anotherpage/ and i would like www.domain.org/anotherpage/

any help is appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Give the following rules a try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /subfolder/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: this does the same as mine. going to my website works with www.domain.org but clicking links in navigation bar adds /subfolder/page

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.org[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [r=301,nc]

//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 subfolder(.*) //$1
```

Comment: Did you change the values accordingly?

Comment: yes i changed where it said domain to my domain name and subfolder to the name of the folder